# Entity Framework Versions Issue

Tags: entity-framework

Have a class library and a WPF application and am trying to contain all the Entity Framework items within the class library and use an interface to get the info out.  Everything is setup but I get this message each time I try it out:

Message "The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception."

When I looked at the Inner Exceptions it appeared it couldn't find version 5.0.0.0 of EntityFramework and when I checked the Reference for it, it was 4.4.0.0.  Tried uninstalling and reinstalling EntityFramework via NuGet but having no luck.  Any ideas on what to try next?

App Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your web.config?

Comment: No it's not a web app, it's in a class library.

Comment: So....maybe your app.config then...?

Comment: Hmm, that looks correct.  Do you also have EF installed on your computer, in addition to pulling it in from NuGet?  Maybe that could be causing an issue.

Comment: I've used it in other projects without a problem on this computer, I have never manually installed it only used NuGet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstalled EntityFramework

Updated Class Library to .Net Version 4.5

Reinstalled EntityFramework

Now all working.

Comment: If this fails for some, try cleaning the project and rebuilding.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a problem with your app.Config prehaps you dont have the following:

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
```

This needs to be in the config file for your application entry point (whatever executable/webapp is running/using your class library)

A key detail to note is that EF4.4 is released inside the EF5 package and is used for non-.NET 4.5 applications (ie if you have .net 4.5 your reference will be 5.0 otherwise with .net 4 it will be 4.4)

Comment: should I change the .net version to 4.5 maybe?

Comment: its completely up to you, EF will work with either (assuming you have the above config for .net 4 or the alternative for .net 4.5) .net4.5 has lots of other cool stuff and i would highly recommend having it installed (for DB performance reasons) but as to weather you use it for your app its very much your decision

Comment: Just to make it clearer, if you upgrading your projects EntityFramework reference from .net40 to .net45 and you're getting the OP's error. You need to change "Version=4.4.0.0" to "Version=5.0.0.0" in the web.config of entry point website.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried changing the version of EF in the webconfig to the current installed version of the EF on the project and everything works smoothly.

Comment: Thanks. Sure enough web.config <section name="entityFramework"...> had version "5.0.0.0" even though my DLL was "4.4.0.0".